# Nested attributes not working when I try to use validation with presence: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

Summary
* Polititians have many Affiliations.
* I have a form for creating a polititian (using form_for)
* I use nested attributes to create affiliations in that form (using fields_for)

The only way I managed to make this work is by disabling a validation requirement in Class Affiliation. I had to disable presence: true for polititian_id

Maybe problem is in the way I use entry_params?
Maybe I shoud use reject_if?

**MODELS**

```
class Polititian < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :affiliations
    has_many :groups, through: :affiliations
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :affiliations 
    validates :first_name, presence: true 
    validates :last_name, presence: true
end

class Affiliation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :group 
    belongs_to :polititian
    #validates :polititian_id, presence: true
    validates :group_id, presence: true 
end
```

**VIEW**

```
<%= form_for (@polititian), :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :first_name, "First name(*)"%>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "First name" %>

    <%= f.fields_for :affiliation do |g| %>
        <%= g.label :group_id, "Partido político(*)"%>
        <%= g.collection_select :group_id, Group.all, :id, :name, {}%>
    <% end %>   

    <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

**POLITITIAN CONTROLLER STRONG PARAMS METHOD**

```
def entry_params
    params.require(:polititian).permit(:id, :first_name, :last_name, :political_position, :political_position_start_at, :political_position_end_at, :avatar, :remote_avatar_url, :affiliations_attributes => [:group_id, :polititian_id] )
end
```